# GNU Fortran 95 compiler GUI?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, gui, fortran

I am new to Ubuntu & Linux.
I installed GNU Fortran 95 compiler.I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
I want to run a code in `fortran 90`.
Where do I go to run the code? Is there a GUI for that? I cant find anything related to the applications bar.